# Can someone redirect or block emails of a specific sender?

Tags: email, account-security

I’m expecting some information from a governmental organisation, they claim that they already send the info via email, but I have never received anything.

They also have an automatic reply email, when I email them, then I don’t even get the automatic reply in my outlook inbox or anywhere else.

The nature and the sensitivity of the information in the mails, and the fact that I miss a lot of emails, got me thinking if this possible, a third party can redirect emails. I don’t know if my scenario is even slightly possible!

I have a feeling that if someone selectively decides which emails should I receive.

I constantly changed my password, and even changed my devices, haven’t opened unknown emails and respect all the basic security steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, any email relay in the chain can block emails.

Are they doing this, specifically, to craft *your* experience? Very highly unlikely.

Before jumping to malicious conclusions, make sure that you have exhausted all technical conclusions first.

Make sure that you check all the normal things like your junk/spam folder and any custom email handling rules.

Email rules brings up the one idea that could be malicious: someone might have gained access to your email account and set up rules. But this is not about some external email system, this is a targetted attack. Unlikely, but possible.

So, check those things on your end, then set up another email account and have them try that instead. All the normal email troubleshooting stuff.

Comment: I struggle with this problem for about three months, I already checked the normal troubleshooting stuff and junk etc. Still no mail, but they send an automatic reply to my gmail I just checked it few seconds ago. About the first line of your answer, could you explain more, I don’t understand. And thank you.

Comment: Well said by Shroeder.  Most likely, all connections between MDAs and MTAs from their end to yours are over SSL/TLS.  So, highly unlikely that an attacker would be able to selectively target just emails to you, because MAIL TO is encrypted by the SSL/TLS channel.

Comment: Any services like anti-spam filters configured in the server may reject e-mails, but this will show in the server log.